# Does the R arrow implementation have flavor='spark' like pyarrow does

Tags: r, apache-arrow

Like the question says, pyarrow has `pq.write_table(..., flavor='spark')` as a parameter

In the R arrow docs I don't see any mention of flavor either in the `write_parquet` function or in the `ParquetWriterProperties$create()` factory method.

Is there an undocumented way to specify the flavor?  Is the flavor defaulting to 'spark' by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flavor` does not exist outside of pyarrow, but by my reading of the pyarrow source, all it is doing is setting `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps = TRUE` and removing characters from field names that are not allowed by Spark, so you can achieve the same effect from R.

Comment: thanks.  As a tangential rant, the field name bit is a fail.  I had to rewrite a ton of parquet files that had column names with spaces b/c spark didn't want to read them.